# Jumping only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some issues with a coding on C# (Unity); I'm trying to make my character move and jump with space. But for some reason, the character jumps once, and when reaching the ground once again, it stops jumping! Could anyone help me? I tried to check and uncheck "Is jumping" and "Double Jump" on Unity, but nothing seems to work D:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float Speed;
    public float JumpForce;

    public bool isJumping;
    public bool doubleJump;

    private Rigidbody2D rig;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Move();
        Jump();
    }

    void Move () {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    }

    void Jump () {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
        {
            if(!isJumping){
                rig.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                doubleJump = true;
            }else{
                if(doubleJump){
                    rig.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                            doubleJump = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
    
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8){
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first rename isJumping to isGrounded - because likely that is what you're testing with right?

Comment: If you add Debug.Log(isJumping); inside your Jump() function right before if(!isJumping) what value do you get after the second jump? Something tells me it never gets set to false again after the first jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in `Jump()` seems sound, so what i'm guessing is that `isJumping` is not being set correctly. It could be that you're on the ground, then jump onto a platform that is not on layer `8`. In that case `OnCollisionEnter2D` will never get called to set your `IsJumping` value.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
    
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8){
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }
```

I've edited your code a bit to make it a little more readable (although some of it is taste) and added some general tips.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// Add https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float Speed;
    public float JumpForce;

    // Naming of booleans should follow guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties
    public bool IsGrounded;
    public bool HasDoubleJumped;

    private Rigidbody2D rig;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Another tip, just write out variable names and don't shorten them (again see the guidelines).
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Move();
        JumpCheck();
    }

    void Move () {
        // Some tips
        // A) try to move any physiscs related movement to fixedUpdate
        // B) try to use .AddForce() to move objects with a rigidbody NOT using transform.position. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
    }

    void JumpCheck () {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
        {
            // Jump if we're grounded
            if(IsGrounded)
            {
                Jump();
                HasDoubleJumped = false;
            }
            // Jump if we're in the air (!IsGrounded) and we haven't double jumped yet.
            else if(!HasDoubleJumped)
            {
                Jump();
                HasDoubleJumped = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // We're in the air and we've double jumped, do nothing!
            }
            

        }
    }
        
     private void Jump() =>
        rig.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
        }
    }
        
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8){
            IsGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to bother, but I would like to know what the Vector3/Vector2 etc means!
Could you tell me please? :0

Comment: @Aserli a `Vector` is basically a pair of axis. `Vector2` has an X and an Y, `Vector3` has an X, Y and Z axis. This is used for positions. Each transform has a position which is a Vector3 in unity. adding +1 to Y moves the object 1 step along the Y axis (upwards), adding -1 moves the object 1 step down the Y axis, so downward, etc. etc.